# C++ overload operator [ ][ ]

Tags: c++, matrix, overloading, operator-keyword

I have class CMatrix, where is "double pointer" to array of values.

```
class CMatrix {
public:
    int rows, cols;
    int **arr;
};
```

I simply need to access the values of matrix by typing:

```
CMatrix x;
x[0][0] = 23;
```

I know how to do that using:

```
x(0,0) = 23;
```

But I really need to do that the other way. Can anyone help me with that?

At the end I did it this way...

```
class CMatrix {
public:
   int rows, cols;
   int **arr;

public:
   int const* operator[]( int const y ) const
   {
      return &arr[0][y];
   }

   int* operator[]( int const y )
   {
      return &arr[0][y];
   }

   ....
```

Comment: There is no `operator[][]` in `C++` and you can't make one up, too...

Comment: "I really need to do that the other way" why? Is it an assignment?

Comment: just overload the [] operator of the item of the array

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Because it's school homework, with exact terms...

Answer (score 30):

You cannot overload `operator [][]`, but the common idiom here is to use a *proxy class*, i.e. overload `operator []` on your Matrix class to return an instance of a different class which then has `operator []` overloaded on it.

For example:

```
class CMatrix {
public:
    class CRow {
        friend class CMatrix;
    public:
        int& operator[](int col)
        {
            return parent.arr[row][col];
        }
    private:
        CRow(CMatrix &parent_, int row_) : 
            parent(parent_),
            row(row_)
        {}

        CMatrix& parent;
        int row;
    };

    CRow operator[](int row)
    {
        return CRow(*this, row);
    }
private:
    int rows, cols;
    int **arr;
};
```

Comment: You might want to make the `CMatrix` class a `friend` of the `CRow` class, or it won't be able to construct a `CRow`.

Comment: Note that this won't work on a `const CMatrix`, you'll need a `const` version of the proxy for that.  You can make `CRow` a template that you instantiate with `CMatrix &` or `const CMatrix &` as appropriate to reduce code duplication.

Answer (score 18):

There is no `operator[][]` in C++. However, you can overload `operator[]` to return another structure, and in that overload `operator[]` too to get the effect you want.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it by overloading `operator[]` to return an `int*`, which is then indexed by the second application of `[]`. Instead of `int*` you could also return another class representing a row, whose `operator[]` gives access to individual elements of the row.

Essentially, subsequent applications of operator[] work on the result of the previous application.

Answer (score 2):

If you create a matrix using Standard Library containers, it's trivial:

```
class Matrix {
    vector<vector<int>> data;

public:
    vector<int>& operator[] (size_t i) { return data[i]; }
};
```

Comment: because this is school homework I cant use any other library thank iostream :(

Comment: That wasn't stated in question requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Some support for this has been added for containers in C++23: [Multidimensional subscript operator](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2128r6.pdf)

Although the syntax used is `v[x, y, z]` rather than `v[x][y][z]`.

Answer (score 1):

You could `operator[]` and make it return a pointer to the respective `row or column` of the matrix. 
Because pointers support subscripting by [ ], access by the 'double-square' `notation [][]` is possible then.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers tell you how you can do it, but...

### Don’t do that.

Instead, overload `operator ()`.

```
int & operator () ( size_t row, size_t col )
{
  // maybe validate `row` and `col` first?
  return arr[row * cols + col];
}
```

### Why not?

The C++ FAQ explains it all. Straight from the horses’ mouths.

- [How do I create a subscript operator for a Matrix class?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#matrix-subscript-op)
- [Why shouldn’t my Matrix class’s interface look like an array-of-array?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#matrix-array-of-array)
- [I still don’t get it. Why shouldn’t my Matrix class’s interface look like an array-of-array?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#matrix-c-style-subscript)

**tl;dr** : encapsulation and safety