# c++ overloading operator [] efficiency

Tags: c++, matrix, operator-overloading

I just wanted to know how to overload the operator [] to acces a matrix within a class, and I found how to that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762878/c-overload-operator).
But, I have a question about this: Which way of changing a matrix will be more efficient?

1: Overloading the operator []: (code extracted from the previous link)

```
class CMatrix {
public:
   int rows, cols;
   int **arr;

public:

   int* operator[]( int const y )
   {
      return &arr[0][y];
   }

   ....
```

Edit: I relied too much on the other example: Should it work this way?

```
   int* operator[]( int const x )
   {
      return &arr[x];
   }
```

2:Using a "normal" method:

```
class CMatrix {
public:
   int rows, cols;
   int **arr;

public:
   void changematrix( int i, int j, int n)
   {
      arr[i][j]=n;
   }
...
```

Edit: Fixed const on changematrix

Comment: 1. are these even equivalent code? 2. you are changing state from a `const` function?

Comment: I would suggest overloading the function operator instead of the index operator.

Comment: Before you proceed, think if you really need this kind of access. In many cases it is cleaner to simply overload operator() for element access; which makes code easier to understand, simple to use and does not require this kind of workaround.

Comment: You may not use operator [], but operator () (unsigned row, unsigned col) to make it easy

Comment: It seems both version are not compilable. You are applying 2 index operator on a double pointer. You should change `arr[i][j]` to `arr[i*cols+j]`. Both methods look same except the first one has syntactic sugar.

Comment: @MohitJain: Two pointers, two indirections, to applications of `[]`... looks about right, doesn't it?

Comment: @crashmstr The code in [1] is copied from the previous link. It's redundant, yes.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Please ignore my comment. I made a mistake in understanding the class intention. I was thinking of 1D array as OP was concerned about performance and confused myself.

Comment: If your matrix dimensions are compile time constant, use std::array of std::array, it would be very efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write correct, readable code and let the compiler worry about efficiency.

If you have performance problems, and if when you run a profiler to measure the performance (which you MUST do before trying to optimize) this code shows up as a performance issue, then you can:

1) Examine the assembly language interpretation of the code generated by the compiler with full optimization enabled, or

2) Try it both ways, measure, and pick the faster one.

The results will be highly dependent on the compiler you are using and the flags you specify for that compiler.

Comment: You haven't shown the initialization of the `arr` member (and you aren't using the `rows, cols` members)   If `arr` is set up properly then the `changematrix()` method looks correct.  The `operator[]` approach doesn't make sense (to me) if the data is a 2D matrix, not a vector -- you are trying to access an element using a single index (unless you are requiring the caller to do the index calculations -- in which case, I'd say: don't do that.)

Answer (score 0):

Neither method will work as you have declared

```
 int **arr;
```

gives no row length information for:

```
  return &arr[0][y];
  arr[i][j]=n;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a third option, using `operator()` instead of `operator[]`:

```
int& operator()(size_t i, size_t j) {
    return arr[i][j];
}
int operator()(size_t i, size_t j) const {
    return arr[i][j];
}
```

The user will then do:

```
CMatrix m = ...
m(1,2) = 5;
std::cout << m(1,2);
```

Other than that, I would really consider whether the way of laying out the data internally the the most efficient. Is this a jagged array? Or do all rows have the same width? If this represents a *rectangle* shaped array (i.e. all rows have the same number of columns) you might be better off storing all elements in a single 1D array, and using some basic arithmetic to locate the correct element.