# How to override [] to make my class looks just like a 3-dimension matrix

Tags: c++, matrix

I have been trying to make a class of a 3-dimension.
I want to make it look like this:

```
 Mat A;
 A[3][4][5] = 1;
```

When the matrix is 2-dimension, 
I may use the code just like

```
int* const operator [] (const int& i)
{
    //printf("in []\n");
    return a[i];
}
```

But how is it going when the matrix is 3-dimension or more?
(I know maybe this can be solved with defining 2 class,
but I wonder how to solve this problem with defining 1 class?)

---

Thanks for Ophir Gvirtzer, I have tried his code and it works like

```
template <size_t D>
class Mat : public std::vector<Mat<D-1>>
{
 public:
    Mat() : std::vector<Mat<D-1>>() {};
    Mat(std::array<size_t,D> sz)
    {
         std::array<size_t, D-1> restSz;
         std::copy(sz.begin()+1, sz.end(),restSz.begin());
         for (auto idx=0; idx< sz[0]; idx++)
         this->emplace_back(restSz);
    }
 };

template <>
class Mat<1> : public std::vector<float>
{
     public:
     Mat() : std::vector<float>() {};
     Mat(std::array<size_t,1> sz) : std::vector<float>(sz[0]) {};
};
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762878/c-overload-operator - just one more indirection.

Comment: Consider changing the interface so that you would do things like `A(3,4,5)=1` to access the array.

Comment: This is not a duplicate! This question is about a tensor of variable dimension.

Comment: Thanks，@Mat(Your nickname  is just the same as my class, what a coincidence). But I ask this question for a 3-dimension solution(since I have show the code which applied for 2-dimension one, which is asked in the page you give(maybe It can provide me with some valuable tips,I am not sure since I have not read that page carefully...)).

Comment: @Hurkyl. Thank you. Maybe you are right, but I ask this question out of curiosity that if there a beautiful way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you want to write a single class that can represent tensors of different dimensions. This can be done in C++ using several Technics, like template specialization, variadic template arguments, initialization lists. Here's a simple code that demonstrates how to achieve this. It's drawback is the usage of nested vectors, which is inefficient, but reduces the necessary coding to minimum:

```
template <size_t D> 
class Mat : public std::vector<Mat<D-1>>
{
public:
   Mat() : std::vector<Mat<D-1>>() {}
   Mat(std::array<size_t,D> sz)
   {
        std::array<size_t, D-1> restSz;
        std::copy(sz.begin()+1, sz.end(),restSz.begin()); 
        for (auto idx=0; idx< sz[0]; idx++)
            emplace_back(restSz);
   }
};

template <> 
class Mat<1> : public std::vector<float>
{
public:
    Mat() : std::vector<float>() {}
    Mat(std::array<size_t,1> sz) : std::vector<float>(sz[0]) {}
};




int main()
{
    array<size_t,3> sz = {5,4,3};
    Mat<3> mat(sz);
    mat[3][3][2]=5;
    mat[3][0][1]=6;
    cout<<mat[3][3][2]<<'\n';
}
```

Comment: Worth noting that this approach buys simplicity at the cost of some efficiency (dynamic allocations for creation and copying, calculations and indirections in indexing).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf If you read carefully, he states exactly that: "It's drawback is the usage of nested vectors, which is inefficient, but reduces the necessary coding to minimum". Though imo this is a good start and a more elaborate solution is only necessary if _measuring_ performance reveals an opportunity of improvement here. There's also applications in which a linear layout of a matrix harms performance (e.g. when the matrix is extended by columns).

Comment: @stefan: Thanks, I didn't see that. But then, that means maybe others don't either.

Comment: There is also the incidental concerns that inheriting from std::vector is rarely considered a good technique, that public inheritance is usually used to model "is-a" relationships, and a Mat<D> is not a Mat<D-1>.   However, it is possible to use aggregation rather than inheritance -i.e. have a Mat<D-1> be a member of Mat<D> and Mat<1> have a member that is a std::vector.

Comment: IMO the main efficiency problem is losing the continuity of the data. I presented this mainly to demonstrate the Technic of template specialization that seems appropriate for this problem. Whether and how to improve efficiency depends heavily on the specific usage of this class. For examples, if the sizes of the tensors are known in advance, replacing vectors with array will solve the issue perfectly. Otherwise, a solution using proxy classes over a 1D array is appropriate (though, using operator () seems much more natural in that case)

Comment: Peter, I think the is-a approch applies here - Mat<D> is a vector of Mat<D-1>. I've considered the aggregation approach, but it seemed to make the code more cumbersome for no good reason.

Comment: Thanks.I have run this code in my PC and it works well. I find I have never used C++11 before...Maybe I should try to learn these new features in C++11. Could you please recommend some books for me about C++11? Thank you very much.

Comment: In fact, this code hardly uses C++11 features - only emplace_back if I count right. But anyway, C++11 (and 14) are great. The best book is probably Stroustrup's  latest addition of "The C++ language". But you don't need books, there's plenty of material online. Some useful links http://blog.smartbear.com/c-plus-plus/the-biggest-changes-in-c11-and-why-you-should-care/                        http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-lambda-closures.html

Comment: Maybe auto is also one of the new features? Many Thanks.