# Implement matrix as a class in C++

Tags: c++, matrix

I need to implement matrix as a class in C++.

This is my class:

```
class {
private:
    int rows, columns;
    int **mat;
};
```

In the main, I need to start the matrix in the regular way. For example : `m[0][0]=1;`

I thought to overloading the `operator[][]` but it is forbidden.

I would like to get some help. thanks.

Comment: Search the internet for "C++ FAQ Matrix".

Comment: Then overload the operator[] and return a row or column (depending on whether you want a math representation of it or a programming representation), then have another overloaded operator for that row/column.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762878/c-overload-operator).

Comment: `int **mat;` -- this isn't going to end well. Use a `std::vector`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ overload operator \[ \]\[ \]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762878/c-overload-operator)

Comment: @Quentin attempting to answer the question before it's asked huh?  If only there was rep for upvoted comments then you'd be rewarded for the prevention rather than cure policy.

Comment: You may find this: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#multidim-arrays4 helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Instead, you could overload the function call operator (`operator()()`), to get something like this:

```
int operator()(int p_row, int p_column);
```

which is legal and clean. I would allow you to write something like this:

```
// Create and fill in matrix called 'm'...
int matrixElement = m(0, 0); // get element m[0][0]
// ...
```

Here is an [example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/function_call_operator_overloading.htm) of how to overload this operator.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have `vector<vector<int>> x`The operator [][] is really (ignoring out of bounds) `vector<int> b = x[0]` then `int = b[0]` combined into one line. I.e accessing the first array then the subscript operator of the second.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data in a continuous array using `std::vector` and then supply your own indexing operator which returns a pointer to the beginning of the row.

```
class Matrix
{
    int rows, columns;
    std::vector<int> data;
public:
    /*...*/

    // The overloaded operator[] returns a pointer to the beginning
    // of the requested row, which can then be indexed for the column
    // without checking the boundaries.
    int* operator[](int r){
        return &data[r*columns];
    }
};
```

Using a vector of vectors is less efficient because the data gets spread to different memory locations. If you need bounds checking you can wrap the pointer in your own class and overload its `operator[]`.